# Nginx giving 400 error:

Tags: nginx, webserver

I am using Nginx to handle hits of API. I checked the access log and found that sometimes Nginx is giving 400 error.

```
GET /url to hit/  HTTP/1.1" **400 172** "-" "-"
```

What is 172 in above log ? and how to solve this error in Nginx ?

Comment: I set the error log at info level and checked the log and found ...client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client: IP, server: , request: /url/to/hit

Comment: Issue resolved.
It was the bug of Nginx. 
Nginx was not handling space followed by **H (Capital H**).

Comment: No, it's not a bug of nginx. It is a bug of client. Please, read [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1), there is only one space can be between `Request-URI` and `HTTP-Version`.

Comment: plz check this http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/196

Comment: So I checked, and the conclusion in this ticket that the client is broken, and it would be nice if nginx can workaround such problems. Not a bug actually, just an enchantment. The real bug is in the client.

Answer (score 0):

172 corresponds to the  **size of server response in bytes**.

Source: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/log-parsing/